# How to change stepSize of RatingBar from 1.0 to 1?

Tags: android, ratingbar

In my xml I set `android:stepSize="1"` but when I implement it. It still show 1.0.

how to change it to 1?

```
rtnCafe.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
             Log.i("rating",""+rtnCafe.getRating());
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "rating " +rtnCafe.getRating(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             txtLove.setText(""+rtnCafe.getRating());

        }
    });
```

Comment: please explain the requirement, if the rating is in float it will show 1.0 always unless you type cast it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast it to `int` like,

```
txtLove.setText(""+(int)rtnCafe.getRating());
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add (int) before rtnCafe.getRating(...